# Axiom consistently divides huge CDATA block into several CDATA blocks

Tags: java, w3c, cdata, axiom

I faced with folowing problem I need to send XML message  with one huge CDATA block via SOAP service.When AXIOM performs processing parameter it has consistently divide one large CDATA block into smaller blocks like this

How I can fix this?

```
try {
   String str = ""; // string which contains xml

   java.io.StringReader stringReader = new java.io.StringReader(str);
   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory inputFactory = javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
   inputFactory.setProperty(javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, false);   
   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);      
   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder builder =
                                  new org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder(streamReader);



       System.out.println("xml = " + builder.getDocumentElement());                                           
} catch (XMLStreamException e) {               
    e.printStackTrace();
```

After processing for test XML:

```
<ns1:customerData><![CDATA[<Root><Project><UserList><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User><User> <ProjectTableID></ProjectTableID> <UserTableID></UserTableID> <OrgLevelName></OrgLevelName> <UserID></UserID> <UserType></UserType> <ShortName> </ShortName> <UserFullName></UserFullName> <UserEmail></UserEmail> <UserPhone></UserPhone> <UserPosition></UserPosition> <IsTerrBank></IsTerrBank> <UnitPostAddress></UnitPostAddress> <UnitPostIndex></UnitPostIndex> </User></UserList></Project></Root>]]></ns1:customerData>
```

will be

```
<ns1:customerData><![CDATA[....previous xml piece....]]><![CDATA[....previous xml piece....]]></ns1:customerData>
```

Comment: @Andreas Veithen gave true answer, it helped. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to rate this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Woodstox as StAX implementation, you could try configuring the following property:

```
inputFactory.setProperty("com.ctc.wstx.minTextSegment", 
                         Integer.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```